# Need to extract whole sentences where middle word begins with a specific word in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract whole sentences where middle word begins with a specific word in R. Below is the code which i am trying to use but not able to get the desired result. I am new to regular expression concept in R. I want to extract the sentences where middle word is 'arent'.

```
  yy <- c("computers arent working", "arent not wkng","scanner arent good","arent scanner good")
  m <- gregexpr('\\w arent ', yy)
  regmatches(yy, m)
```

Above code does not gives what i want. My desired output is:

```
 "computers arent working", "scanner arent good"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is middle word specifically the second word or any word that's not first or last?

Comment: Maybe just `grep(" arent ", yy, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)`? Do you have more complicated examples there?

Comment: Hi Eli - It should be second word.

Comment: For 3 word phrases, `grep("\\w arent \\w", yy, value=TRUE)` will work.

Comment: Thanks David and Imo for your direction. Its working.

Comment: Be aware that "aren't" is misspelled here so that might give you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
grep("\\w\\W+arent\\W+\\w", yy, value = TRUE)
```

`grep` will find all the strings that match the regex pattern (where a *partial match* is found), and will output the values themselves (as `value` is set to `TRUE`).

The regex pattern matches `arent` *in-between* word (`\w`) chars and only enclosed with 1+ non-word (`\W+`) chars.

[Online R demo](http://ideone.com/kRw2N1):

```
yy <- c("computers arent working", "arent not wkng","scanner arent good","arent scanner good")
grep("\\w\\W+arent\\W+\\w", yy, value = TRUE)
## => [1] "computers arent working" "scanner arent good"
```

If the word you seek to match MUST be enclosed with whitespace, replace `\\W+` with `\\s+` (1 or more whitespaces).